# Netlogo- not a valid property name in gis extension

Tags: netlogo

I have imported my shape file via gis extension and want to transfer attribute to my patch. for some of the properties it works, but for some of them I get this error:

```
Extension exception: shima is not a valid property name
error while observer running GIS:APPLY-COVERAGE
  called by procedure COLOR-PATCHES
  called by Button 'color-patches'
```

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 0):

I have noticed that if **define a name with capital letters** for the properties, there won't be any error.